# i need to use ngrx-translate in my angular porgramm without dependency injection

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-translate

```
export const assetDepreciationProgressColumn: ExtendedAssetColumn = new AssetColumnBuilder()
  .specifyAssetType(AssetType.Depreciation)
  .setColumn({
    ...intColumn<DepreciatingAsset>(
      { id: 'dp', displayHeader: 'depreciation progress' },
      (x): number => getDepreciationProgress(x, 'minute') * hundred
    ),
    tooltip: (
      a: DepreciatingAsset
    ): string => //translated tooltip>
      `${(getDepreciationProgress(a, 'minute') * 100).toFixed(2)}% actually depreciated, ` +
      `${((a.bookings.filter(x => Boolean(x.doneAt)).length / a.bookings.length) * hundred || 0).toFixed(2)}% booked`,
    bookedProgress: (a: DepreciatingAsset) =>
      (a.bookings.filter(x => Boolean(x.doneAt)).length / a.bookings.length) * hundred,
  })
  .build();
```

Here is the one of the column in my table, i need to translate "actually depreciated" and "booked"   with ngrx-translate without DI

Comment: Is it some sort of a util function that you are trying to avoid DI? If so, you have two options: 1. provide TranslateService as a parameter to the function 2. Provide translated values as parameters

Answer (score 0):

i make an injectble service from my const, and then i can inject translate service in my class in constructor

```
    @Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
    export class AssetsColumns {
      constructor(private readonly translateService: TranslateService) {}
    
      assetDepreciationProgressColumn: ExtendedAssetColumn = new AssetColumnBuilder()
        .specifyAssetType(AssetType.Depreciation)
        .setColumn({
          ...intColumn<DepreciatingAsset>(
            { id: 'dp', displayHeader: 'depreciation progress' },
            (x): number => getDepreciationProgress(x, 'minute') * hundred
          ), // actually idk why there was condition that makes progress bars full with '-' value),
          tooltip: (a: DepreciatingAsset): string =>
            `${(getDepreciationProgress(a, 'minute') * 100).toFixed(2)}% ${this.translateService.instant(
              'assets.progress.actuallydepreciated'
            )}, ` +
            `${((a.bookings.filter(x => Boolean(x.doneAt)).length / a.bookings.length) * hundred || 0).toFixed(
              2
            )}% ${this.translateService.instant('assets.progress.booked')}`,
          bookedProgress: (a: DepreciatingAsset) =>
            (a.bookings.filter(x => Boolean(x.doneAt)).length / a.bookings.length) * hundred
        })
        .build();
```